# Adding a Key to csv erb template output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

Currently in my `create.csv.erb` template I have this.

`<%- event_headers = @event_filters -%>`

`<%= CSV.generate_line(event_headers) %>`

It generates a CSV file like this

`event1,event2,event3,event4`

I would like to add some sort of Key or header, so that the output looks like this

`Events: event1,event2,event3,event4`

or like this

```
Events:

event1,event2,event3,event4
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [string interpolation](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/5-strings/lessons/31-string-basics) to construct string you wish to have :)

```
<%= "Events: #{CSV.generate_line(event_headers)}" %>
```

Comment: Figured it out right before you posted.  

`<%- event_headers = ["Events: #{@event_filters.join(" ")}"] -%>`